# QGIS Scalebar Font Outline

Tags: qgis, text, font, scale-bar

Is there a way to add a text buffer or stroke the text on the scale bar?

Its impossible to read the scale when its set on a map with dark colours.

Comment: This is answered here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/420032 But the question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options. In the item properties of the scalebar:

- Set the background color to white.
- Set the font color to white.

or make a footer with white background where you also can put logo etc.

[image]