# Border surround point text in QGIS 3.22?

Tags: qgis, style, text

Point text was just released in [QGIS 3.22](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog322/index.html). Is there a way to create a black border around the text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the new annotation layers, see [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#annotation-tools).

To create a frame around your text, proceed as follows:

1. Use the `Mask` tab, check the box `Draw background`, set `Shape` to rectangle
2. Click on the `Configure symbol` bar (red arrow in the screenshot) and as `Symbol layer type` select `Outline: simple line` and style the line as you wish.
3. To have the text in the middle of the frame, you might need to adapt values: select `Size type : Buffer` and set value for `Size X`, `Size Y` and `Offset X,Y`.

[image]

Comment: This looks perfect! I will try it out!

Comment: This works great!! Thanks!!

Comment: It is possible to create point text annotations that are driven from a spatial dataset (specifying latitude & longitude) or from python code?

Comment: Please post this as another question - here in the comments, it gets lost.

Answer (score 7):

- If you don't use a buffer around the text, you can use a buffer for the border.

  Before:
  [image]

  After:
  [image]
- If you also want to use a buffer, you can use "Layer Rendering" > "Draw effects" for the buffer.

  [image]

Comment: I guess you mean a frame by border, right? The answer is about the strokes of the letter. :(

Comment: Correct I meant border and not strokes of the letter.